# How to writing a python code to combine multiple csv to excel , without having number read as text ..in excel?

Tags: python, excel, csv

I'm using this csv reader to read all my csv file then combine into xls workbook. But after open excel all number from csv is now read as text.

In each csv it has both letter and number. Is there a way I can compress all number value from csv to let excel know it's number not text ?

```
import glob, csv, xlwt, os

wb = xlwt.Workbook()
for filename in glob.glob("d:/test/*.csv"): 
    (f_path, f_name) = os.path.split(filename)
    (f_short_name, f_extension) = os.path.splitext(f_name)
    ws = wb.add_sheet(f_short_name)
    spamReader = csv.reader(open(filename, "rt"))

    for rowx, row in enumerate(spamReader):
        for colx, value in enumerate(row):
            ws.write(rowx, colx, value)
wb.save("d:/test/compiled.xls")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library, which would also connect you with the overall Python Data Science Stack.  Pandas will be smart enough to correctly interpret the data types for Excel.

```
import glob, os
import pandas as pd

from pandas import DataFrame, ExcelWriter

writer = ExcelWriter("d:/test/compiled.xlsx")

for filename in glob.glob("d:/test/*.csv"):
    df_csv = pd.read_csv(filename)

    (_, f_name) = os.path.split(filename)
    (f_shortname, _) = os.path.splitext(f_name)

    df_csv.to_excel(writer, f_shortname, index=False)

writer.save()
```

You open a spreadsheet for writing, read each CSV as a Pandas [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html), and then write the `DataFrame` to the sheet on a separate tab.  The `index=False` piece is there so that Python doesn't write the default `DataFrame` index to the sheet, which would give you an extra unwanted column.

Comment: This actually did not solve the issue because appending make all the csv combined into one sheet , instead of assign to multiple sheets. Thank you.

Comment: OK it is fixed.

Comment: Unfortunately this will run into memory issues if your CSVs are very large

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way:

```
            for rowx, row in enumerate(spamReader):
                for colx, value in enumerate(row):
                    try:
                      value = float(value)
                    except ValueError:
                      pass
                    ws.write(rowx, colx, value)
```